# Angular mat dialogue not saving multiple values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mat-table, mat-dialog

I am using `Anular9` and using `mat-raised-button` as below:

```
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="saveClick()" color="primary"><mat-icon>check</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ok</button>
```

The `saveClick()` is defined as below

```
saveClick() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.hostid.length; i++) {
        const saudit: SInterface = {
            data: this.data,
            eid: this.eid[i],
            serverId: this.hostid[i]
        };
        this.subs.sink = this.sservice.addRecord(saudit)
            .subscribe(s => {
                this.dialog.close();
            });
    }

}
```

Here `data`is common for all the records.

The above code is only saving the first record with `i=0`.
How to change `saveClick()` so that it saves all records until `i < this.hostid.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.

Rather than using for loop, try using map, once you will have array of saudits then call your service with it as a param.

BTW. Move  your call to service outside of the loop / map.

** Edit
I don't know your business logic exactly, but I would use that mapping at least as strting point.

```
    // Map each Id in the hostid array to SInterface
    const saudits: SInterface = this.hostid.map((id, index) => {
      return {
        data: this.data,
        eid: this.eid[index],
        serverId: id,
      } as SInterface;
    });

    // Pass all saudits at once to service
    this.sservice.addRecord(saudits).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: can you please let me know how the updated code would look like using `map`?